# How to sort alphanumeric string in groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy, alphanumeric

How to sort alphanumeric values using groovy ?For example : I have list of values [ADF1SD23GF12,UTRR453FGT3,NKUY43ERT5,56GHY123,MU157FGR234,...] I want to get result as in Excel sorting for this values. Could someone help?

List1.sort{ a,b -> a <=> b
}

Comment: provide the expected output. "as in Excel" is not enough

Comment: i don't think excel using any sort magic. usual sort should work: `List1 = List1.sort()`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thaks to all. I'll create a new topic, the task is more comlicatede then I have discribed.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some differences between what you're after and what the close to the default sorting does, but you can modify this example to get there:

```
def arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

arr.sort() { a, b -> a.compareTo( b ) }
println( arr )

arr.sort() { a, b -> a.compareTo( b ) * -1 }
println( arr )
```

Prints:

```
[four, one, three, two]
[two, three, one, four]
```

Of course you can simply the first one to simply:

```
arr.sort()
println( arr )
```

But I left it with the closure to illustrate how to sort ascending vs descending.